# Контекстная реклама

Tags: реклама, google-adwords, яндекс-директ

Открыл аккаунт в google adwords, но меня заблокировали. Сказав что у меня подозрительные платежи или что-то такое (я пополнял счет с вебмани, техподдержка гугла не отвечает уже пару дней).

Знаю, что есть посреднические фирмы, которые помогают запустить контекстную рекламу сразу и в google adwords и в yandex direct. (на подобии begun.ru).

Скажите, если я буду работать через эти фирмы, то меня так же будут блокировать по пустякам?
Подскажите, где, как и через кого можно запустить контекстную рекламу, чтобы это было максимально быстро и просто и как можно меньше всяких официальных формальностей?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, не заблокируют, т.к. Формально рекламу будет давать посредник, а не Вы.
Я пользуюсь иногда яндекс директом, попробуйте.

Comment: Немного не понял. Кто не заблокирует? Вы имеете ввиду через посредника надо работать?

Comment: либо так, либо делать другой аккаунт на жену/тещу/собаку. Я сделал на жену. Если будете пользоваться бегуном и пр., не заблокируют, т.к. Бегун размещает от своего имени а не от Вашего.

Comment: Был рад помочь.